# Setting up a tap interface on linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I'm using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) to learn how to craft packets however I seem to be getting some interference from the kernel when trying to do some specific operations. I have been given some advice to use a tap interface so I can work easier with the raw packets on a local machine, however I'm having a difficult time setting it up to work correctly.

So far what I have done is this:

> [me@localhost hw1]$ ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
> [me@localhost hw1]$ ifconfig tap0 192.168.0.254 up
> [me@localhost hw1]$ route add -host 192.168.0.253 dev tap0

My routing table then has the following entry

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface    
192.168.0.253   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap0
```

When I try running `tcpdump` on tap0, and pinging it, tcpdump doesn't show any packets going to tap0.

I'm basically trying to set up a virtual interface where I can use to sniff and send packets using Scapy. If anyone can help point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.